# LHS and RHS both keypaths

Tags: core-data, ios7, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Trying to find active `guestCards` where a `prospectiveTenant` matches all of the search queries. Possibilities are `firstName`, `lastName`, `phoneNumber`.

`prospectiveTenants` is a to-many on `guestCard`.

This code:

```
NSString *predicateString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"active=1"];
if (self.searchHeader.firstNameTextField.text.length > 0) {
    predicateString = [predicateString stringByAppendingFormat:@" AND (ANY prospectiveTenants.firstName CONTAINS[cd] %@)", self.searchHeader.firstNameTextField.text];
}
if (self.searchHeader.lastNameTextField.text.length > 0)
{
    predicateString = [predicateString stringByAppendingFormat:@" AND (ANY prospectiveTenants.lastName CONTAINS[cd] %@)", self.searchHeader.lastNameTextField.text];
}
if (self.searchHeader.phoneNumberTextField.text.length > 0)
{
    predicateString = [predicateString stringByAppendingFormat:@" AND (ANY prospectiveTenants.phone CONTAINS[cd] %@)", self.searchHeader.phoneNumberTextField.text];
}

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateString];
[self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
```

produces this error

```
'unimplemented SQL generation for predicate : (ANY prospectiveTenants.lastName CONTAINS[cd] S) (LHS and RHS both keypaths)'
```

Answer (score 7):

Gah.

So it looks like `predicateWithFormat` does special work to make sure quotes are inserted around strings. Should have been obvious.

Comment: Thank you, so the fix is to change %@ into \"%@\"

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to use the work the `NSPredicate` init does, try building up the format string and the values to be placed in the string as two variables and then pass them both when creating the `NSPredicate`.

This has the advantage of taking care of any other special work `NSPredicate` might like to do.

Re-writing in Swift, this would become:

```
var predicateString = "active=1"
var predicateParameters = [Any]()

if !self.searchHeader.firstNameTextField.text.isEmpty {
    predicateString.append(" AND (ANY prospectiveTenants.firstName CONTAINS[cd] %@)")
    predicateParameters.append(self.searchHeader.firstNameTextField.text)
}
if !self.searchHeader.lastNameTextField.text.isEmpty {
    predicateString.append(" AND (ANY prospectiveTenants.lastName CONTAINS[cd] %@)")
    predicateParameters.append(self.searchHeader.lastNameTextField.text)
}
if !self.searchHeader.phoneNumberTextField.text.isEmpty {
    predicateString.append(" AND (ANY prospectiveTenants.phone CONTAINS[cd] %@)")
    predicateParameters.append(self.searchHeader.phoneNumberTextField.text)
}

let predicate = NSPredicate(format: predicateString, argumentArray:predicateParameters)
self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
```